# How to create an image with height as pixel values

Tags: python, matlab, matrix

I want to create a jpg image with size 343 by 389 (Height by Width) with height as pixel values. For example for the whole topmost pixels, I need to give it as value 1, the next row of pixels should have a value 2. and finally, the last pixel with value 343. then export that image in jpg format. How to do this? either in python or in Matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did it

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
a = np.empty(shape=(343, 389), dtype=int)

for i in range(343):
    for j in range(389):
        a[i,j]=i
im = Image.fromarray(a,'L')

im.save('depth.jpg')
```

Answer (score 2):

### In MATLAB

A solution in MATLAB using the `meshgrid()` function may work. An important part is to caste the array `Image` of type `double` into an unsigned 8-bit integer array, `uint8` before exporting it as a `.jpg` using the `imwrite()` function.

---

[image]

---

```
[~,Image] = meshgrid((1:389),(1:343));
imwrite(uint8(Image),"Depth.jpg");
```